# How to change the dtid of the Twin in Azure Data Twin Explorer

Tags: azure, azure-digital-twins

How to change the dtid of the Twin in Azure Data Twin Explorer

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The DTID can't be changed as it uniquely identifies the twin.
You probably want to add a "name" string property to your model in order to be able to change the id/name of your "Shop1" twin.